# Array filter javascript

Tags: javascript

My goal is to add a `multiSelect`.

[This plugin multiSelect](http://loudev.com/#demos)

So, I created an object that contains two lists.

`events` and `events_sel`

I want to use an event list to fill the checkbox.

and I want to use the `events_sel` list to mark the selected events, and everything that doesn’t exist in `events_sel` becomes available in the checkbox.

In the small example below, create an object simulating this situation, but I'm not sure that I can use `array filter` for this.

Or if you would have to use a loop.

And yet, I was not able to separate the list as in the superficial example inside the `filter`, below.

```js
const object = {
  events: [
    { id: 1, description: "event 1" },
    { id: 2, description: "event 2" },
    { id: 3, description: "event 3" },
    { id: 4, description: "event 4" },
    { id: 5, description: "event 5" },
  ],
  events_sel: [{ event_id: 1 }, { event_id: 2 }],
};

let events = object.events;
let eventsSel = object.events_sel;

// array filter
events.filter(function (event, i) {
  //console.log(eventsSel[i].event_id)
  if (event.id == 1 || event.id == 2)
    console.log(`Selecionado: ${event.description}`);
  else
    console.log(`Não Selecionado: ${event.description}`);
});

// for
for (const event of events) {
  //console.log(event);
}
```

My final goal is to replace this excerpt `if (event.id == 1 || event.id == 2)` with the data that is in the list `events_sel`

Comment: Please edit your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: The callback function needs to return a boolean that indicates whether to include the element in the result. And it doesn't modify the list in place, it returns a new list, so you need to assign the result.

Comment: Why is `events_sel` an array of objects instead of an array of IDs? If it were `events_sel: [1, 2]` you could use `if (eventsSel.includes(event.id))`

Comment: With the array of objects, use `if (eventsSel.some(el => el.event_id == event.id))`

Comment: @Barmar Ah perfect, I didn't know the `some()` method

Comment: @Barmar Will you write as an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `some` method, and assign the result back to `events`.

```js
const object = {
  events: [
    { id: 1, description: "event 1" },
    { id: 2, description: "event 2" },
    { id: 3, description: "event 3" },
    { id: 4, description: "event 4" },
    { id: 5, description: "event 5" },
  ],
  events_sel: [ { event_id: 1 }, { event_id: 2 } ],
};
let events = object.events;
let eventsSel = object.events_sel;

// Array filter
events = events.filter(function(event, i) {
  // console.log(eventsSel[i].event_id)
  return eventsSel.some((el) => el.event_id == event.id)
});

// for
for (const event of events) {
  console.log(event);
}
```